# Are trace of powers of linear combinations of self-adjoint matrices a complete invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $A_1, \dots, A_N$ self-adjoint $d \times d$ matrices.

I was wandering if the knowledge of the polynomials
$$ P_k(x_1,\dots,x_N) = \mathrm{Tr} \left( (x_1A_1 + \dots + x_NA_N)^k \right) $$
for every integer $k \geq 1$ suffices to determine $(A_1,\dots,A_N)$ up to rotation.

That is, if another $N$-tuple of self-adjoint matrices $B_1,\dots,B_N$ gives the same sequence of polynomials $(P_k)_{k \geq 1}$, does it follow that $B_i=UA_iU^{-1}$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$ ?

This is easy for $N=1$ and I also checked it for $d=2$.

Comment: Over the complex field the answer is in general no. If $A_1,\ldots,A_{d^2}$ is a basis of Hermitian matrices for the space of $d\times d$ complex matrices then $A_1^t,\ldots,A^t_{d^2}$ gives the same sequence of polynomials. If there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A_i^t=UA_iU^*$ for every $i$ then the transposition map $T(X)=X^t=UXU^*$, but we know that this is impossible. The transposition is not a completely positive map.

Comment: This is a very nice insight. I was mostly thinking about the real case. You can try to restore the question by asking whether the tuple is determined up to unitary conjugacy and transposition.

Comment: Your question is really asking whether a spectrum preserving linear transformation $T:span\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}\rightarrow span\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$, which sends $A_i$ to $B_i$, can be written as $T(X)=UXU^t$. For the full matrix algebra, we know that $T(X)=UXU^t$ or $T(X)=UX^tU^t$ (See proposition 1, item a) of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290377M and recall that in your case $T(Id)=Id)$.